# Struggling with context inflating a RecyclerView list item

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, fragment, android-context, layout-inflater

After following many tutorials on RecyclerViews I keep getting my app to crash on this line:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.layout_listitem, parent, false);
```

Which is probably caused by the inflater object being null since the context is null:

```
LayoutInflater inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
```

However, I don't understand why it is null if I am passing the context in the constructor of the RecyclerViewAdapter:

```
public RecycleViewAdapter(Context context) {
    this.context = context;    
}
```

from my fragment activity:

```
View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) view.findViewById(R.id.matches);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));
    recyclerView.setAdapter(new RecycleViewAdapter(getActivity()));
    return view;
```

And I have tried getContext(), getActivity(), I even override onAttach method to get the context from there and still crash. I am new to using fragments so I don't really know what I am doing, just using solutions people have tried on forums.

Logcat:

```
09-07 09:48:14.433 7594-7594/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                             Process: maginate.net.thebestrapper, PID: 7594
                                             java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)' on a null object reference
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:722)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:813)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:511)
                                                 at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:415)
                                                 at maginate.net.thebestrapper.RecycleViewAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(RecycleViewAdapter.java:40)
                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6685)
                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5869)
                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5752)
                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5748)
                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2232)
                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1559)
                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1519)
                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:614)
                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3812)
                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3529)
                                                 at android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4082)
                                                 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16916)
                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5405)
                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
                                                 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16916)
                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5405)
                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
                                                 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16916)
                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5405)
                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1702)
                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1556)
                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
                                                 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16916)
                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5405)
                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
                                                 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16916)
                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5405)
                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1702)
                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1556)
                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
                                                 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16916)
                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5405)
                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
                                                 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16916)
                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5405)
                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1702)
                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1556)
                                                 at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1465)
                                                 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16916)
                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5405)
                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:579)
                                                 at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:514)
                                                 at android.view.View.layout(View.java:16916)
                                                 at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5405)
                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2413)
                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2122)
                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1264)
                                                 at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6942)
                                                at
```

Comment: `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'boolean java.lang.String.equals(java.lang.Object)'`

Answer (score 1):

Method 1:-
Pass the parent context using adapter constructor then use the constructor context.

Method 2:-
Use parent Context like this:-

```
@Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
this.context = parent.getContext();
        RecyclerView.ViewHolder vh;

        View v = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.anylayout, parent, false);
        vh = new RowVH(v);

        return vh;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to pass a `Context` instance to your `Adapter`.

Make sure you only try to bind your layout in the `onCreateViewHolder()` method of your adapter, you can get the `Context` from the `parent` param:

```
new YourViewHolderClass(LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.your_layout_xml, parent, false));
```